# Flickering on [Form].[Recalc] in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working with MS Access 2013 and have a calculation that needs to be updated every time underlying values are changed.  The 'Record' per se doesn't need to be updated, just a 'monitoring' value prior to the record being saved.

The form has 12 fiscal year months (October - September) and a "currency" value is entered into each textbox.  Each time the total value for all of the textboxes needs to appear at the bottom every time it is changed.  Currently it does, but it flickers dramatically.

The structure is as follows:

Each textbox has the following formula in the AfterUpdate: `=[Form].[Recalc]`

The "Total" textbox has the following formula:

```
=Nz([txtOCT_Nc],0)+Nz([txtNOV_NC],0)+Nz([txtDEC_NC],0)+Nz([txtJAN_NC],0)+Nz([txtFEB_NC],0)+Nz([txtMAR_NC],0)+Nz([txtAPR_NC],0)+Nz([txtMAY_NC],0)+Nz([txtJUN_NC],0)+Nz([txtJUL_NC],0)+Nz([txtAUG_NC],0)+Nz([txtSEP_NC],0)
```

Is there VBA or a setting that can prevent the flickering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Application.Echo False` to turn off screen updating while the Recalc runs. Though I'm a bit surprised that a simple sum would cause dramatic flickering.

Create a function like this in the form module:

```vb
Private Function MyRecalc()

    Application.Echo False
    Me.Recalc
    Application.Echo True

End Function
```

and change the control's AfterUpdate to

```
=MyRecalc()
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked - there is still a minor flicker, but the dramatic flickering ceased.  I also wondered why a simple sum would cause dramatic flickering.